# Update list to keep first matching condition and remove subsequent items

Tags: python

I'm attempting to transform the list :

```
data = [['e' , 1] , ['e' , 2], ['b' , 3], ['c' , 4], ['e' , 5], ['e' , 6], ['e' , 7], ['b' , 8]]
```

Such that for each e (at position 0 in the sub list) until something other than 'e' is found remove the intermediary list values that contain 'e'.

So the expected output for above `data` is :

```
[['e' , 1] , ['b' , 3] , ['c' , 4] , ['e' , 5], ['b' , 8]]
```

I'm unsure how to implement this. I have written :

```
updated_list = []
for index, segment in enumerate(data) :
    if segment[0] == 'e' and data[index + 1][0] == 'e' :
        updated_list.append(segment)
print(updated_list)
```

which produces :

```
[['e', 1], ['e', 5], ['e', 6]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an attempt using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

data = [['e', 1], ['e', 2], ['b', 3], ['c', 4],
        ['e', 5], ['e', 6], ['e', 7], ['b', 8]]

ret = []
for key, item in groupby(data, lambda x: x[0] == 'e'):
    if key:
        ret.append(next(item))
    else:
        ret.extend(item)
```

as a 'one-liner' this might be

```
from itertools import groupby, islice, chain

ret = list(chain.from_iterable(islice(item, 1 if key else None) for key, item in
                               groupby(data, lambda x: x[0] == 'e')))
```

both variants return

```
[['e', 1], ['b', 3], ['c', 4], ['e', 5], ['b', 8]]
```

the logic is the same for both: if the group starts with `'e'` in the first position, only add the first element of that group. for groups that do not start with `'e'` add all elements.

---

your approach only appends the item at `index` if the current and the subsequent items start with `'e'`.

this might be a fix:

```
e_start = False
ret = []
for item in data:
    if item[0] == 'e':
        if not e_start:
            ret.append(item)
            e_start = True
    else:
        ret.append(item)
        e_start = False
```

`e_start == True` means that the last item started with `'e'`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `for-loop` with conditionals and set a variable to keep track if the last seen item contains `e`.

```
last_seen_is_e = False
updated = []
for item in data:
    if not last_seen_is_e or item[0] != "e":
        updated.append(item)
    if item[0] == "e":
        last_seen_is_e = True
    else:
        last_seen_is_e = False

[['e', 1], ['b', 3], ['c', 4], ['e', 5], ['b', 8]]
```